# I cannot find the Sencha Cmd in the sencha-touch-2.0.0-gpl file?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, cmd, sencha-touch-2

I can not find the Sencha Cmd in the `sencha-touch-2.0.0-gpl` file and SenchaSDKTools file.  Can someone point it out to me, or is there a reason that it is not there?

Comment: sencha cmd is not included in sencha-touch-gpl. You need to download separately. you don't need sdk tools if you download cmd. You can either use sdktools or cmd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sencha Cmd is not provided with the framework. You need to download it separately

Also so you need to know that you Sencha Cmd does not work with Sencha Touch 2.0. It only works with Sencha Touch 2.1.0 and latest versions.

If you really don't want to upgrade to Sencha Touch 2.1 (which I don't recommend) then you need to use Sencha SDK Tools.

[Download Sencha Cmd for Sencha Touch > 2.1.0](http://www.sencha.com/products/sencha-cmd/download) - [Documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/guide/command)

[Download Sencha SDK Tools for Sencha Touch < 2.1.0](http://www.sencha.com/products/sdk-tools) - [Documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/command)